# Music Manager(s) cannot find certain album

Tags: music, music-player, htc-one, doubletwist

I recently added a new album on my phone and my music manager (neither doubleTwist or the system music app) have indexed it.

(Failed) Attempts

- I have tried deleting the whole album and re-uploading it
- I have recently replaced my whole library and while they found every other album, it could not find this one
- I have tried the "Reset doubleTwist" button.

Additional Information

- The album is located at "HTC One\Internal storage\Music\Slipknot\The Grey Chapter".
- It does have every other album in the HTC One\Internal storage\Music\Slipknot\ folder. and every other album I own
- I can find it in my phones file manager and from there use it to play the song
- It IS in MP3

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or how to fix it?

Comment: How did you "add" it?

Comment: @DanHulme I plugged my phone into my computer and copied it from my desktop into the respective folder

Comment: Check if there is a file in the same folder that is called ".nomedia", if there is delete it. Better look for it on a PC, or enable the option to view hidden files in your phone's file manager to see it. The presence of such a file informs the system media indexer to ignore this folder.

Comment: You could re-run media scanner after removing the .nomedia file (if there is one). Can you move it to `Internal storage\Media` and see if that helps? HTC can be a bit... weird indexing media sometimes.

Comment: Sweet! Sometimes it's something simple that makes no sense, no HTC sense wah wah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

- If there is a **hidden** file named *.nomedia* in that particular album folder >>> (unhide the file and delete it).
- Move the folder into some other directory and refresh library.
- Check whether .mp3 files have proper tags (IDv3 tags) >>> (or else they go to unknown album category).